# Correlation Coefficient of #DIV/0!

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

I am trying to ask Excel to make a correlation matrix for variables that affect the Chinese exchange rate. However, since I found data with labor cost having a base year (2019), I ended up with lots of "#DIV/0!" in the boxes of that matrix. Could I manually solve this or do I have to find new data?

Thanks in advance.